# Access global array from perl module file

Tags: arrays, perl

I have arraytest.pm with below

```
package arraytest;

our @myarray = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
```

and i'm trying to get the values from a different perl script

```
use arraytest;

foreach (@arraytest::myarray) {
  print "$arraytest::myarray\n";
}
```

I get nothing printed and no errors as well. Pleas let me know if referencing the array is correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `use warnings;` to get more errors to be printed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You trying achieve something like:

```
use 5.012;
use warnings;

package MyArr;
our @arr = (1..10);

package main;
for (@MyArr::arr) {
    say "$_";
}

#or like above with a helper variable
for my $val (@MyArr::arr) {
    say "$val";
}
```

Ps: the above is usually not a good practice. Use objects instead.

Edit - @dave's comment

```
use 5.012;
use warnings;

package MyArr {
    our @arr = (1..10);
}

package main {
    for (@MyArr::arr) {
        say "$_";
    }

    for my $val (@MyArr::arr) {
        say "$val";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input and info on object.

Comment: Because `our` has a lexical effect, you don't need to use the fully qualified name (`@MyArr::arr`) in either of your `for` loops. Switching from `package MyArr` to `package main` does not create a new lexical scope. To force the need for the fully qualified name (which is what you're trying to demonstrate here) you need to put a naked block around the two lines of the MyArr package.

Comment: @DaveCross of course, youre right. But, the OP asking for `different perl script`. Sure, i can write the two file example, one for package MyArr and second file for main and require the MyArr from the main - but this was not the main point of the question... (imho)

Answer (score 5):

Yer array syntax is wrong.

Perl does not have array literals. It has

- Lists: `1, 2, 3, 4`
- Array references literals: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
- Hash reference literals: `{1 => 2, 3 => 4}`.

Hashes and arrays can be initialized by assigning lists.

Instead, you intitialized your array to contain one hash reference as first element. This is equivalent to

```
my %hash = (1 => 2, 3 => 4);
our @myarray = (\%hash);
```

What you meant to do was

```
our @myarray = (1, 2, 3, 4);  # parens needed because of precedence
```

or

```
our @myarray = 1 .. 4;
```

---

Oh, and please do not use lowercase names for your packages. These are reserved for *pragmatic modules* that affect compilation, like `strict` or `feature`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion on naming the packages and braces. I got it working now.

Answer (score 3):

Always use

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

The problem is that you are trying to write content of `$arraytest::myarray` variable which doesn't exist at all. Try this:

```
foreach my $val (@arraytest::myarray) {
  print "$val\n";
}
```

and also your array doesn't contain what you expect. You have hash ref in first cell of array. You should use:

```
our @myarray = ("1", "2", "3", "4");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried this, but I get a hash output instead of the items in the array  HASH(0x4f8360)

Comment: @user2628187 That's because you are initializing your array to conatain a hash reference (see my answer for details). You get such output when you print a hashref. The last snippet in Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil's answer shows you how to correctly initialize your array (use parens, not braces).

Comment: Sorry It was my mistake .. was using {"1", "2", "3", "4"}; instead if ("1", "2", "3", "4");... It worked  thanks a lot